# stored procedure CONCAT() Error Code 1054, Unknown column

Tags: mysql, insert, procedure, concatenation

thanks in advance for you help. you guys are awesome.

having trouble with CONCAT() inside a stored procedure. trying to create an INSERT INTO with variables.

ERROR CODE 1054, Unknown column 'Milk' in field list.

Milk is a value to be inserted, not a column.

Here is the CODE:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('insert into ',USR,' (Product, ProdId, ListName) VALUES (',food_name,',',PRODID,',',LISTID,')');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the value of `food_name`:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('insert into ',USR,' (Product, ProdId, ListName) VALUES (\'',food_name,'\',',PRODID,',',LISTID,')');
```

As it is, MySQL will see the unquoted value `Milk` and assume it's a column name instead of a string literal.

If other columns in the list are also character types, you need to do the same for those columns as well. For example, making the assumption that `ListName` is also a character type, your procedure would be:

```
SET @s = CONCAT(
    'insert into ',
    USR,
    ' (Product, ProdId, ListName) VALUES (\'',
    food_name,
    '\',',
    PRODID,
    ',\'',
    LISTID,
    '\')'
);
```

Comment: okay, thank you. PRODID and LISTID are INT type. Also, there are other values that need to be INSERTed. Having had trouble with this for too long, I cut the CONTAT() as far as possible.

Comment: so far so good...your edit worked.  I'll add the other fields in the same way you suggested.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, it gets confusing fast with all the commas and quotes :-)